# Wrong number of stars in chatroom information page

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

According to the badge on [this page](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1251/trashcan?tab=stars), the Trashcan chatroom has 7 stars:

[image]

but if you count the number of stars under Starred posts, you'll only get to 2. What happened to the remaining 5?

Answer (score 6):

> What happened to the remaining 5?

Deleted.

For example:

[image: deleted chat message with stars]

Comment: OK, that might explain it, but I'd still expect the badge number to be consistent with the search results ...

Comment: Well, naturally the total starred messages count isn't live for efficiency reasons, it's taking from some static source, that currently isn't being synched when messages are deleted. Making it synch is the ideal solution, hopefully they'll do it at some point.